# How to get equal line and paragraph spacing with flushbottom?

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir

I've written two novels so far using LaTeX, however I've had to take great pains to use flushbottom to produce even line/paragraph spacing (I had an obsession with getting the lines on opposing pages to line through). This has often meant I needed to change wording to prevent widows from causing gaps at the bottom of the page. I feel the need not to do this in future, as it seems stupid to sacrifice content just to fulfil layout, and most professionally published novels in fact allow their line spacing to change to eliminate widows. I normally have parskip and parsep set to zero, so the spacing is even (using flushbottom and then tweaking, as above) but if I remove the parskip and parsep settings, the document will eliminate the space, but the distance between paragraphs is different to the distance between lines.

How do I use flushbottom for this automatic spacing increase such that the distance between paragraphs and lines is the same? It's too jarring to have the space between paragraphs different to the space between lines, especially when novels are formatted with first line indentation.

Comment: it is of course much easier to have even spacing with raggedbottom, if you use flushbottom then you have to ensure that everything inserted on the page is an exact multiple of `\normalbaselineskip` otherwise you are setting impossible constraints that can not be achieved.

Comment: but set `\setlength\parskip{0pt}` will stop the inter paragraph space ever stretching

Comment: I'd hoped flushbottom would allow the lines to 'spread out' to fill the page (to a certain degree), which it does, but only by increasing the inter-paragraph spacing, which makes paragraphs stand out, so I'm trying to find out whether all of the spacing can spread out evenly so there aren't different gaps between paragraphs and lines. I don't mind removing the parskip setting as long as everything ends up the same spacing.

Comment: you can  adjust the word spacing to avoid widows (using `\looseness`) and the `widows-and-orphans` package will alert you where that is necessary.

Comment: I'll take a look at that as an option - at the moment, the only setting I have in relation to widows and orphans is
\setnoclub[1] 
\setnowidow[2]

Comment: inter-line spacing is fixed, by default you could make it stetchy but then the interline spacing on each page will be different and the results are unlikely to be good (but `\baselineskip=1\baselineskip plus 1pt` will make it stretchy if you want to try.

Comment: Those commands must be from some package, I don't recognise them.

Comment: Ah yes, they are from the nowidow package. I'll give the baselineskip stretching a go - I think that's what I want to do. Traditionally published novels seem to use it, but obviously I have to check each page for tolerance. Thanks!

Comment: using nowidow in that way with \flushbottom really makes it impossible for tex. Unlike looseness it does not change the linebreaking it just says "do not break the page here" (if that would leave a widow line)  but if you don't break there the only possibility is to break the line above leaving the page short. But \flushbottom says the page should not be short....

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully through well-published non-technical (text only)
books, you will probably find occasional facing pages that are both one
line longer or shorter than the preceding or following pair of pages.
This is a traditional technique used by compositors to maintain visually
grid-locked pages of the same length.  (It's easiest to spot such pages
in books printed on non-opaque paper.)

Implementing this must be done as the very last thing, starting at the
beginning and testing often.  The coding is
`\enlargethispage{<number>\baselinekip}`,
where the number is `1` to add a line, and `-1` to shorten by a line, and
this must be added on facing pages.  The most reliable place to add it is
at a paragraph break before a paragraph that is certain to appear on that
page.  Test often.

Before doing this, it's worth trying to compress longish paragraphs with
short last lines with `\looseness=-1` tacked onto the end of the paragraph
or to expand paragraphs that are set tight or have long last lines by
inserting `\looseness=1` at the end of the paragraph, as suggested in a
comment by David Carlisle.  This may be done either on the page to be
changed or up to several pages earlier, as long as it doesn't affect any
pages in between.  Again, this usually requires several reruns, starting
at the beginning.

By "beginning" is meant separately for any chapter or similar chunk that
starts on a new page.  Be careful that your changes don't cause the text
to expand to an extra right-hand page, which would result in the insertion
of an extra blank page between chapters, and an increase of two pages in
the total.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Barbara. I'll possibly look into that for my next book if it worries me enough. I think one of the ideas I have it may not be worth the effort of checking (or even be controllable), since it's going to have randomly ordered sections that would be difficult to typeset, but thanks for the response! I suspect others may also find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to David Carlisle's comments, the closest I've achieved to what I want has been to use:

```
\baselineskip=1\baselineskip plus 1pt
```

Given most of my pages are almost entirely full except for the odd blank line at the bottom, this gives decent results without appreciable differences in paragraph to line spacing.